# Why does StackExchange.Redis use ThreadPriority.AboveNormal?

Tags: multithreading, stackexchange.redis

The 'read' and 'write' threads that service each socket connection that SE.Redis establishes to a Redis server are created with `ThreadPriority.AboveNormal`.

I want to use SE.Redis in services where talking to Redis is not necessarily the highest-priority / most-latency-sensitive thing that is going on, and I have concerns about having the SE.Redis threads elevated in priority.

Comment: Hmya, lets call it "performance tuning", the SE redis servers no doubt have a wholeheckaofalot of cores given the very high page serving rate.  If you don't like it then just change it.

Comment: Sure - it's open source (thank you, Mark Gravell!), so it is not hard to change, at the price of forking. But I am also interested in any info regarding WHY above normal priority is used. All of the guidance I have read regarding thread priorities on Windows boils down to "don't do this in your code - you will just mess with the scheduler"

Comment: This should be configurable